# I ran into a RecursionError when I ran the MIT 6.0001 F16 pset5 ps5.py

Tags: python

When I was doing the pset5 of MIT 6.0001 Fall 2016 course, After the completion of previous parts. I was doing the filtering part of the pset, figure as following.

[image]

So after I ran the ps5.py, I get the repeated error message:

File "/Users/eric.ling/Desktop/Introduction to Computer Science and Programming in Python/pset5/mtTkinter.py", line 138, in _Tk__init__
    self.**original__init__mtTkinter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/eric.ling/Desktop/Introduction to Computer Science and Programming in Python/pset5/mtTkinter.py", line 138, in _Tk__init**
    self.__original__init__mtTkinter(*args, **kwargs)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
I don't know where I did wrong, can someone help?

```
# 6.0001/6.00 Problem Set 5 - RSS Feed Filter
# Name:
# Collaborators:
# Time:

import feedparser
import string
import time
import threading
from project_util import translate_html
from mtTkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
import pytz


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#======================
# Code for retrieving and parsing
# Google and Yahoo News feeds
# Do not change this code
#======================

def process(url):
    """
    Fetches news items from the rss url and parses them.
    Returns a list of NewsStory-s.
    """
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    entries = feed.entries
    ret = []
    for entry in entries:
        guid = entry.guid
        title = translate_html(entry.title)
        link = entry.link
        description = translate_html(entry.description)
        pubdate = translate_html(entry.published)

        try:
            pubdate = datetime.strptime(pubdate, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
            pubdate.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("GMT"))
          #  pubdate = pubdate.astimezone(pytz.timezone('EST'))
          #  pubdate.replace(tzinfo=None)
        except ValueError:
            pubdate = datetime.strptime(pubdate, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")

        newsStory = NewsStory(guid, title, description, link, pubdate)
        ret.append(newsStory)
    return ret

#======================
# Data structure design
#======================

# Problem 1

# TODO: NewsStory
class NewsStory(object):
    def __init__(self, guid, title, description, link, pubdate):
        self.guid = guid
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.link = link
        self.pubdate = pubdate
    def get_guid(self):
        return self.guid
    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
    def get_description(self):
        return self.description
    def get_link(self):
        return self.link
    def get_pubdate(self):
        return self.pubdate

#======================
# Triggers
#======================

class Trigger(object):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        # DO NOT CHANGE THIS!
        raise NotImplementedError

# PHRASE TRIGGERS

# Problem 2
# TODO: PhraseTrigger
class PhraseTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger):
        self.trigger = trigger.lower()
    def is_phrase_in(self, text):
        text = text.lower()
        for mark in string.punctuation:
            text = text.replace(mark, ' ')
        text = ' '.join(text.split())
        if self.trigger in text:
            counter = text.count(self.trigger)
            for n in range(counter):
                loc = text.find(self.trigger)
                if loc == 0:
                    flag1 = 1
                else:
                    if text[loc-1] == ' ':
                        flag1 = 1
                    else:
                        flag1 = 0
                try:
                    if text[loc+len(self.trigger)] == ' ':
                        flag2 = 1
                    else:
                        flag2 = 0
                except IndexError:
                    flag2 = 1
                if flag1 == 1 and flag2 == 1:
                    return True
                else:
                    text = text[len(self.trigger)-1:]


        return False

# Problem 3
# TODO: TitleTrigger
class TitleTrigger(PhraseTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.is_phrase_in(story.get_title())


# Problem 4
# TODO: DescriptionTrigger
class DescriptionTrigger(PhraseTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.is_phrase_in(story.get_description())       

# TIME TRIGGERS

# Problem 5
# TODO: TimeTrigger
# Constructor:
#        Input: Time has to be in EST and in the format of "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S".
#        Convert time from string to a datetime before saving it as an attribute.
class TimeTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, time_trigger):
        self.utc = pytz.UTC
        self.time_trigger = datetime.strptime(time_trigger, "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=self.utc)

# Problem 6
# TODO: BeforeTrigger and AfterTrigger
class BeforeTrigger(TimeTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        pubdate = story.get_pubdate().replace(tzinfo=self.utc)
        return self.time_trigger > pubdate

class AfterTrigger(TimeTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        pubdate = story.get_pubdate().replace(tzinfo=self.utc)
        return self.time_trigger < pubdate


# COMPOSITE TRIGGERS

# Problem 7
# TODO: NotTrigger
class NotTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger_object):
        self.trigger_object = trigger_object
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return not self.trigger_object.evaluate(story)

# Problem 8
# TODO: AndTrigger
class AndTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger_object1, trigger_object2):
        self.trigger_object1 = trigger_object1
        self.trigger_object2 = trigger_object2
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.trigger_object1.evaluate(story) and self.trigger_object2.evaluate(story)


# Problem 9
# TODO: OrTrigger
class OrTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, trigger_object1, trigger_object2):
        self.trigger_object1 = trigger_object1
        self.trigger_object2 = trigger_object2
    def evaluate(self, story):
        return self.trigger_object1.evaluate(story) or self.trigger_object2.evaluate(story)


#======================
# Filtering
#======================

# Problem 10
def filter_stories(stories, triggerlist):
    """
    Takes in a list of NewsStory instances.

    Returns: a list of only the stories for which a trigger in triggerlist fires.
    """
    # TODO: Problem 10
    # This is a placeholder
    # (we're just returning all the stories, with no filtering)
    result = []
    for story in stories:
        for trigger in triggerlist:
            if trigger.evaluate(story):
                result.append(story)
                break
    return result



#======================
# User-Specified Triggers
#======================
# Problem 11
def read_trigger_config(filename):
    """
    filename: the name of a trigger configuration file

    Returns: a list of trigger objects specified by the trigger configuration
        file.
    """
    # We give you the code to read in the file and eliminate blank lines and
    # comments. You don't need to know how it works for now!
    trigger_file = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = []
    for line in trigger_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not (len(line) == 0 or line.startswith('//')):
            lines.append(line)

    # TODO: Problem 11
    # line is the list of lines that you need to parse and for which you need
    # to build triggers

    print(lines) # for now, print it so you see what it contains!



SLEEPTIME = 120 #seconds -- how often we poll

def main_thread(master):
    # A sample trigger list - you might need to change the phrases to correspond
    # to what is currently in the news
    try:
        t1 = TitleTrigger("election")
        t2 = DescriptionTrigger("Trump")
        t3 = DescriptionTrigger("Clinton")
        t4 = AndTrigger(t2, t3)
        triggerlist = [t1, t4]

        # Problem 11
        # TODO: After implementing read_trigger_config, uncomment this line 
        # triggerlist = read_trigger_config('triggers.txt')

        # HELPER CODE - you don't need to understand this!
        # Draws the popup window that displays the filtered stories
        # Retrieves and filters the stories from the RSS feeds
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

        t = "Google & Yahoo Top News"
        title = StringVar()
        title.set(t)
        ttl = Label(master, textvariable=title, font=("Helvetica", 18))
        ttl.pack(side=TOP)
        cont = Text(master, font=("Helvetica",14), yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        cont.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        cont.tag_config("title", justify='center')
        button = Button(frame, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
        button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        guidShown = []
        def get_cont(newstory):
            if newstory.get_guid() not in guidShown:
                cont.insert(END, newstory.get_title()+"\n", "title")
                cont.insert(END, "\n---------------------------------------------------------------\n", "title")
                cont.insert(END, newstory.get_description())
                cont.insert(END, "\n*********************************************************************\n", "title")
                guidShown.append(newstory.get_guid())

        while True:

            print("Polling . . .", end=' ')
            # Get stories from Google's Top Stories RSS news feed
            stories = process("http://news.google.com/news?output=rss")

            # Get stories from Yahoo's Top Stories RSS news feed
            stories.extend(process("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories"))

            stories = filter_stories(stories, triggerlist)

            list(map(get_cont, stories))
            scrollbar.config(command=cont.yview)


            print("Sleeping...")
            time.sleep(SLEEPTIME)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Some RSS parser")
    t = threading.Thread(target=main_thread, args=(root,))
    t.start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could we see the code you're running?  Without that, there's no way to see what's going on.  That being said, the error you're getting occurs when you have a function which, directly or indirectly, calls itself.  There's nothing wrong with that per se.  However, you run into trouble when the stack of function calls gets too deep.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code.  Is that the entirety of the error message being printed or is there a fuller traceback?

Comment: the error message is the repeating sentence: File "/Users/eric.ling/Desktop/Introduction to Computer Science and Programming in Python/pset5/mtTkinter.py", line 138, in _Tk__init__ self.__original__init__mtTkinter(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: You will get a much better error message (with stacktrace) if you don’t use `except Exception` to catch all errors.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't done anything wrong. GUI problem occurred. Simply by restarting Spyder you will avoid this error.
P.S. if you run into problem "object has no attribute 'description'", i suggest removing yahoo news.

Comment: Ugh, same problem.  Seems like the program runs successfully once, then after that I have to restart spyder (or just restart kernel) or will get that recursion error.  Is this really a GUI problem, or perhaps a problem with mtTkinter.py not cleaning up after itself somehow?  Didn't find many hits for the problem, but those that I found were all recent (2020).  Guessing it could be a change in python?

Answer (score -1):

Can vouch for Uros answer, that is correct (including the YahooNews component).

One note: the RSS feed will not close properly for me. When I run it I need to force quit it for it to shut. However, if I stop the feed by hitting "Exit" before I force close the feed, it allows me to rerun the program without the recursion error.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. More of a question. Please don't put stuff like this in the answers section.